# PxProjection - how to use filter parameters in the Select class?

Tags: acumatica

I use PxProjection attribute in a way that select the specific fields of DACs. How should I pass filter parameter in the select command(the same way as it is in the graph by using  `Or<CRInsurancePolicy.currentreportsTo, Equal<Current<BAccountParam.bAccountID>>>` ) in order to have filtered data in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to look at Select2 attribute in PXProjection.
Select2 attribute allows to use filter - all possible commands of BQL (Join, Where, GroupBy, OrderBy).

For examle here, the attribute joins data from two table and projects it to the single DAC:

```
[Serializable]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<Supplier,
    InnerJoin<SupplierProduct,
        On<SupplierProduct.accountID, Equal<Supplier.accountID>>>>))]
public partial class SupplierPrice : IBqlTable
{
    public abstract class accountID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
// The field mapped to the Supplier field (through setting of BqlField)
[PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(Supplier.accountID))]
public virtual int? AccountID { get; set; }
public abstract class productID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
// The field mapped to the SupplierProduct field
// (through setting of BqlField)
[PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(SupplierProduct.productID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product ID")]
public virtual int? ProductID { get; set; }
...
}
```